# ASP.NET Framework 2 very slow startup windows server 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an ASP.Net web application that was running on windows server 2003 when running the application for the 1st time on the server (after deployment or restarting the server) it takes about 30 seconds to launch. After migrating to windows server 2012 it takes about 2.5 minutes.

Is there a certain feature or an option on windows server 2012 that makes application much slower?

Comment: do you have too much code on  `App_Code`  ?

Comment: @Aristos No plus it was working fine on 2003

Comment: Could be some optimizations in the IIS on the old server that is not included on the new one. Hard to say with no further information.